# Delegating Syntax Highlighting of Embedded language when writing an IntelliJ Syntax Highlighting Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing an IntelliJ plugin to do syntax highlighting for the Scala implementation of Jade.  Jade is an HTML templating language which can include embedded code.  for example:

```
-@ var teams : List[Team]
div(id="TeamList")
    ul
        =teams foreach {view(_, "list")}
```

Everything after the "-@" and the last "=" is embedded Scala code.  My plugin handles the Jade syntax highlighting but I do not want to repeat the Scala Highlighting.  Is there a way to delegate the syntax highlighting of the Scala code to the already existing Scala Plugin?

Comment: You use injected language fragments. Which you host in your code, and delegate the work of highlighting them to the scala plugin. Check out PsiLanguageInjectionHost and other similarly named classes.

Comment: Hi Spencer, unfortunately I cannot help you with that question - but I am very interested in that plugin for Jade highlighting in IntelliJ. Is there any chance, you might share that? Thanks a lot! - Jerry

Comment: @Spencer did you ever make something? I've been looking for just this. Using the Node Jade plugin makes IntelliJ one unhappy camper as I'm sure you've seen.